# Java Inter-thread communication in socket programming issues

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, java-io

I started working on Java Socket programming. I had already made following apps:
1. client send message to server and server responds on recieving
2. client and server are chatting like Point to point chat

Now i want to develop an application in which, whenever a request arrives at server, it'll generate a thread for it. But now the problem is, i am unable to recognize the threads. If one thread is sending message then how server can identify that a message came from this client and i have to forward this to that client. how two clients (actually their threads) can communicate?

I searched on it, i found synchronized keyword and i know its use, i know about wait(), notify() and notifyAll() but still i am unable to provide a communication between them.

Please give me knowledge regarding this if i am doing something wrong or i need to know about some concepts before jumping into this one.
TIA

Comment: What about just adding an ID to each single client thread?

Comment: I can add name also, i know but how to recognize the threads? As i am using same run() method for both threads.

Comment: Add a method to the main thread, which passes the ID to it and then notifies().

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass data to threads, you can only pass data to a data structure they are reading.

I suggest you use this simple pattern using two threads per connection and an output queue.  These threads are created when the connection is accepted and run until the connection is closed. You can use a thread pool if you have short lived connections.

Each connection has a reader thread which reads from the socket until the connection is closed using blocking IO. THis reading thread also processes the work on the clients behave.

Another thread for each connection reads from a BlockingQueue for a message which it writes to the socket.

When a user connects they pass a unique token to say who they are and this is stored in a `ConcurrentMap<String, BlockingQueue>` where the BlockingQueue is the output queue for that connection.

This way whenever a connection sends a message to go to a particular users, you add it to the queue associated with that user.

You can reduce this model to use less threads e.g. with Selectors you only need one thread, but this is much more complex.

Comment: I know Peter Lawrey that threads cannot communicate directly but can communicate through a shared resource. by the way, I also know that there are Input and Output Streams associated with each client's thread. And i found your ConcurrentMap suggestion interesting. I'll try for it. If you can share a link of video or any resources related to it where i can learn it then i'll be thankful to you. :)

Comment: @SandeepDass When you have a new connection, use `Map.put`, When you want to find the queue for it use `Map.get` and when you close the connection use `Map.remove`  I suggest you read the Javadoc for the class and it's parents. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html